# Problems when using Powershell to Batch to Groovy Output Append (>>) Redirection

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, groovy

I know this is not the preferred way of doing things but I have a complex batch (.bat) that I created in the past. I now have a new need to call the batch with different arguments that requires calculation. So I used powershell (.ps1) to do the calculation and feed it as an argument of the batch. The batch calls a groovy (v3.0.4) program internally and outputs to stdout.

When I append (>>) redirect groovy's stdout output by switching between batch (.bat: specify argument directly) and powershell (.ps1: specify argument through calculation), I find `[\x0]` being printed between each character of groovy stdout. This only happens for powershell (.ps1) redirection. I have already circumvented the problem by creating a perl program to remove them: `s/[\x0]//g;`.  However I want to know what is going on.

I have simplified the setup to reproduce the problem. The problem can be reproduced when executing **run.bat** below. If you open the appended (>>) redirected file (print.log) with a Windows NotePad you will see that there are gaps between each character. If you then open the same file with a binary editor or a binary viewer, then you will see that the gaps are actually `[\x0]`. Here is the description of the setup.

#### Content of Main Batch File (run.bat)

```
call printBatch.bat -key=value '-key2=value2' "-key3=value3" > print.log
powershell printPowerShell.ps1 print
```

#### Content of printPowerShell.ps1

```
.\printBatch.bat -key=value '-key2=value2' "-key3=value3" >> ($args[0] + ".log")
```

#### Content of printBatch.bat

```
java groovy.ui.GroovyMain ./print.groovy %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

#### Content of print.groovy

```
for (int argIndex = 0; argIndex < args.size(); argIndex++) {
    println("[${argIndex}] = \"${args[argIndex]}\"")
}
```

Insertion of `[\x0]` between each character of groovy's stdout only happens when switching between batch to powershell and only on powershell redirection. Please note that powershell (.ps1) file contains the append (>>) redirection. If it was only append (>>) redirected using just the batch or just the powershell exclusively then this does not occur.

Comment: The `>>` redirection is using its default Unicode output. If you're using at least PowerShell version 3.0, you could probably change that, using `$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"Out-File:Encoding"="ASCII"}` in your `.ps1` file first. That should change your preference for the rest of that PowerShell . session. Alternatively don't use the redirection method and choose `Add-Content` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you [Compo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6738015/compo) for the information. I know the original setup was all ASCII, I learned that if the groovy prints non-ASCII character and/or if .ps1 contains non-ASCII character like so (key4＝value4, "終わり"):

#### Content of printPowerShell.ps1

```
.\print.bat -key=value '-key2=value2' "-key3=value3" key4＝value4 >> ($args[0] + ".log")
```

#### Content of print.groovy

```
for (int argIndex = 0; argIndex < args.size(); argIndex++) {
    println("[${argIndex}] = \"${args[argIndex]}\"")
}
println("終わり") // End in Japanese
```

The content of the **printPowerShell.ps1** should be changed as follows:

#### ---> Content of printPowerShell.ps1

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues = @{"Out-File:Encoding"="default"}
.\print.bat -key=value '-key2=value2' "-key3=value3" key4＝value4 key5＝value5 >> ($args[0] + ".log")
```

**Additional Version Info (for reference)**

- Windows 10 Home (version: 1903, Build: 18362.1082, Japanese)
- CommandPrompt: 10.0.18362.1082
- PowerShell: 5.1.18362.752
- Groovy: v3.0.4